# Foreign key constraint fails when saving a new record with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to save a new record to SQLite with Rails, but with no success so far.

I have a table for "sections," with a column for "sectioncode," which is referenced by another table called "spaces," as "sectioncode_id." Sections have a `has_many` relationship with spaces.

Section:

```rb
Section(id: integer, sectioncode: integer, name: string, description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Space:

```rb
Space(id: integer, spacecode: integer, name: string, description: text, sectioncode_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

(where `sectioncode_id` references the `sectioncode` column of a section)

In Section.rb:

```rb
has_many :spaces, foreign_key: :sectioncode_id, primary_key: :sectioncode, dependent: :destroy
```

In Space.rb:

```rb
belongs_to :section, foreign_key: :sectioncode_id, primary_key: :sectioncode, required: true
```

In the migrate file for creating Spaces:

```rb
t.references :sectioncode, foreign_key: {to_table: :sections}
```

When I try to save a new record to Spaces, Rails says `SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)`.

**TL;DR: Rails reports an Invalid Foreign Key, but SQLite itself doesn't.**

I tried to see if I could create the record manually through the SQLite console, and I was able to, without any errors. When I did this, Rails handled the relationship correctly for all other actions I performed. I used the same command reported by Rails with SQLite.

From Rails:

```
TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Space Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "spaces" WHERE "spaces"."spacecode" = ? AND "spaces"."sectioncode_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["spacecode", 1], ["sectioncode_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Space Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "spaces" ("spacecode", "name", "description", "sectioncode_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["spacecode", 1], ["name", "S1"], ["description", "D1"], ["sectioncode_id", 1], ["created_at", "2023-04-02 00:16:19.836125"], ["updated_at", "2023-04-02 00:16:19.836125"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction              
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.6.1-x86_64-darwin/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step': SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)                                              
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.6.1-x86_64-darwin/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step': FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (SQLite3::ConstraintException)
```

But, a section with `["sectioncode", 1]` does exist:

```
3.0.0 :013 > Section.find_by!(sectioncode: 1)
  Section Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."sectioncode" = ? LIMIT ?  [["sectioncode", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 =>                                                            
#<Section:0x00007ff41089a010                                   
 id: 4,                                                        
 sectioncode: 1,                                               
 name: "Sec1",                                                 
 description: "Desc1",                                         
 created_at: Sun, 02 Apr 2023 00:16:12.260733000 UTC +00:00,   
 updated_at: Sun, 02 Apr 2023 00:16:12.260733000 UTC +00:00>
```

On SQLite:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO "spaces" ("spacecode", "name", "description", "sectioncode_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1, "S1", "D1", 1, "2023-04-02 00:16:19.836125", "2023-04-02 00:16:19.836125");
sqlite>
```

This managed to save the record with the correct foreign key relationship.

Why does this happen? Where exactly is it failing?

Edit:
Here's the code I'm using to save a new space:

```rb
space = Space.new(spacecode: 1, name: "S1 (Seeded)", description: "D1", sectioncode_id: 1)
space.save
```

Comment: You say "When I try to save a new record to Spaces ..". Please show the corresponding Ruby code.

Comment: Why don't you use the default primary keys like Ruby on Rails suggest (`id`)? This just makes it harder for you because you need to override all defaults in the application. And you will need to ensure that, for example, the `sectioncode` is unique on yourself. And even when you want to have a very specially formatted primary identifier, then it would still be easier to just name it `id`, handle the `id` value manually and still depend on Rails' magic on associations and querying.

Answer (score 0):

This sets up a a constraint on `spaces.sectioncode_id` to reference `sections.id`:

```rb
t.references :sectioncode, foreign_key: {to_table: :sections}
```

```rb
>> Section.create!(sectioncode: 100)
=> #<Section:0x00007fbfffa8a0e0 id: 1, sectioncode: 100>
>> Space.create!(spacecode: 1, sectioncode_id: 100)
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (SQLite3::ConstraintException)
```

because `spaces.sectioncode_id` `100` does not match `sections.id` `1`.

In sqlite, you have to enable foreign key check:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
1
sqlite> INSERT INTO "spaces" ("spacecode", "sectioncode_id") VALUES (1, 123);
Runtime error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (19)
```

---

Here is how to fix it:

```
create_table :sections do |t|
  # you need to have a unique index
  t.integer :sectioncode, index: {unique: true}
end

create_table :spaces do |t|
  t.integer :spacecode
  # add constraint for correct columns
  t.references :sectioncode,
    foreign_key: {to_table: :sections, primary_key: :sectioncode}
end
```

```rb
>> Section.create!(sectioncode: 100)
=> #<Section:0x00007fbfffa8a0e0 id: 1, sectioncode: 100>
>> Space.create!(spacecode: 1, sectioncode_id: 100)
=> #<Space:0x00007fbfff78ab38 id: 1, spacecode: 1, sectioncode_id: 100>
```

---

`spacecode` and `sectioncode` seem unnecessary, you're duplicating the role of `id`. If anything both should just be named `code`:

```rb
# if I have a `space`
space = Space.first
space.code
# if I have a `section`
section = Section.first
section.code
```

It would be much simpler this way:

```rb
create_table :sections do |t|
  t.integer :code
end

create_table :spaces do |t|
  t.integer :code
  t.references :section, null: false, foreign_key: true
end
```

```rb
class Space < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
end

class Section < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :spaces, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
>> Space.create!(code: 1000, section: Section.create!(code: 100))
=> #<Space:0x00007f20613bc3a0 id: 1, code: 1000, section_id: 1>
```